# Is there a "concise" way to do namespacing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I've frequently encountered sites that put all of their JavaScript inside a `namespace` structure along the lines of:

```
namespaces = { com : { example: { example.com's data} }
```

However, setting this up safely with respect to other namespaced frameworks seems to require a relatively hefty amount of code (defined as > 2 lines).  I was wondering whether anyone knows of a concise way to do this? Furthermore, whether there's a relatively standard/consistent way to structure it? For example, is the `com` namespace directly attached to the global object, or is it attached through a namespace object?

[Edit: whoops, obviously `{com = { ... } }` wouldn't accomplish anything close to what I intended, thanks to Shog9 for pointing that out.]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have stand-alone namespaces. It has functions, which can provide scope for resolving names, and objects, which can contribute to the named data accessible in a given scope.

Here's your example, corrected:

```
var namespaces = { com: { example: { /* example.com's data */ } } }
```

This is a variable `namespaces` being assigned an object literal. The object contains one property: `com`, an object with one property: `example`, an object which presumably would contain something interesting.

So, you can type something like **namespaces.com.example.*somePropertyOrFunctionOnExample*** and it'll all work. Of course, it's also ridiculous. You don't have a hierarchical namespace, you have an object containing an object containing an object with the stuff you actually care about.

```
var com_example_data = { /* example.com's data */ };
```

That works just as well, without the pointless hierarchy.

**Now**, if you actually *want* to build a hierarchy, you can try something like this:

```
com_example = com_example || {};
com_example.flags = com_example.flags || { active: false, restricted: true};

com_example.ops = com_example.ops || (function()
    {
       var launchCodes = "38925491753824"; // hidden / private
       return {
         activate: function() { /* ... */ },
         destroyTheWorld: function() { /* ... */ }
       };
    })();
```

...which is, IMHO, reasonably concise.

Comment: Although, now `com_example` is going to be part of the global object. Assume we add many more objects `com_something_else`, `com_etc`, then we are still polluting the root level of the global object. Would it not be preferable if we had only one `com` object in global where all other objects were added? Also, we don't want to overwrite any existing objects, what if multiple libraries are being used.

Comment: @Peter: if multiple libraries define the same symbols, you're going to have problems no matter what; that's why libraries like jQuery go to such lengths to stuff everything into a single global object. My point wasn't that you *should* use multiple top-level objects, merely that faking namespaces with deeply-nested objects doesn't really buy you anything over crazy-long object names. See my last example for a more practical method: use a single global name that's unlikely to collide, and then a technique that allows disparate bits of code to add objects to it.

Answer (score 12):

Here was an interesting article by Peter Michaux on [Javascript Namespacing](http://peter.michaux.ca/article/7944).  He discusses 3 different types of Javascript namespacing:

1. Prefix Namespacing
2. Single Object Namespacing
3. Nested Object Namespacing

I won't plagiarize what he said here but I think his article is very informative.

Peter even went so far as to point out that there are performance considerations with some of them.  I think this topic would be interesting to talk about considering that the new ECMAScript Harmony plans have dropped the 4.0 plans for namespacing and packaging.

Answer (score 6):

I try to follow the Yahoo convention of making a single parent object out in the global scope to contain everything;

```
var FP = {};
FP.module = {};
FP.module.property = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 5):

To make sure you don't overwrite an existing object, you should so something like:

```
if(!window.NameSpace) {
    NameSpace = {};
}
```

or

```
var NameSpace = window.NameSpace || {};
```

This way you can put this at the top of every file in your application/website without worrying about the overwriting the namespace object. Also, this would enable you to write unit tests for each file individually.

Answer (score 3):

The [YUI library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yahoo/) library has code which handles namespacing using a function which you may find preferable. Other libraries may do this also.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a dot or an underscore, you could use the dollar sign character:

```
var namespaces$com$example = "data";
```

Comment: What benefit does this provide?

Comment: By doing it this way, you don't have to define your namespaces as an object with nested inner objects. You can just define the name anywhere.

Comment: I still don't see the benefit of using the $ sign instead of a dot or underscore. I think the $ sign makes the word harder to read than a dot or an underscore.

Comment: I think it's much worse than using nested objects - you have tons of separate variables which - no matter if global or local - will make debugging a hell when you look at the currently defined variables.

Answer (score 1):

I like also this ([source](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#anonymous_function_for_clean_namespace)):

```
(function() {
    var a = 'Invisible outside of anonymous function';
    function invisibleOutside() {
    }

    function visibleOutside() {
    }
    window.visibleOutside = visibleOutside;

    var html = '--INSIDE Anonymous--';
    html += '<br/> typeof invisibleOutside: ' + typeof invisibleOutside;
    html += '<br/> typeof visibleOutside: ' + typeof visibleOutside;
    contentDiv.innerHTML = html + '<br/><br/>';
})();

var html = '--OUTSIDE Anonymous--';
html += '<br/> typeof invisibleOutside: ' + typeof invisibleOutside;
html += '<br/> typeof visibleOutside: ' + typeof visibleOutside;
contentDiv.innerHTML += html + '<br/>';​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object literal and either the `this` object or the explicit name to do namespacing based on the sibling properties of the local variable which contains the function. For example:

```js
var foo = { bar: function(){return this.name; }, name: "rodimus" }
var baz = { bar: function(){return this.name; }, name: "optimus" }

console.log(foo.bar());
console.log(baz.bar());
```

Or without the explicit `name` property:

```js
var foo = { bar: function rodimus(){return this; } }
var baz = { bar: function optimus(){return this; } }

console.log(foo.bar.name);
console.log(baz.bar.name);
```

Or without using `this`:

```js
var foo = { bar: function rodimus(){return rodimus; } }
var baz = { bar: function optimus(){return optimus; } }

console.log(foo.bar.name);
console.log(baz.bar.name);
```

Use the `RegExp` or `Object` constructor functions to add name properties to counter variables and other common names, then use a `hasOwnProperty` test to do checking:

```js
 var foo = RegExp(/bar/);
 
/* Add property */
foo.name = "alpha";

document.body.innerHTML = String("<pre>" + ["name", "value", "namespace"] + "</pre>").replace(/,/g, "&#09;");

/* Check type */
if (foo.hasOwnProperty("name")) 
  {
  document.body.innerHTML += String("<pre>" + ["foo", String(foo.exec(foo)), foo.name] + "</pre>").replace(/,/g, "&#09;");
  }

/* Fallback to atomic value */
else 
  {
  foo = "baz";
  }

var counter = Object(1);

/* Add property */
counter.name = "beta";

if (counter.hasOwnProperty("name")) 
  {
  document.body.innerHTML += String("<pre>" + ["counter", Number(counter), counter.name] + "</pre>").replace(/,/g, "&#09;");
  } 
else 
  {
  /* Fallback to atomic value */
  counter = 0;
  }
```

The DOM uses the following convention to namespace HTML and SVG Element interface definitions:

- HTMLTitleElement
- SVGTitleElement
- SVGScriptElement
- HTMLScriptElement

JavaScript core uses prototypes to namespace the `toString` method as a simple form of polymorphism.

**References**

- [Does javascript autobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216847/1113772)
- [Getting sibling value of key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216496/1113772)
- [MDN: JavaScript Operators - this as an object method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)
- [Lua: technical note 7 - Modules and Packages](https://www.lua.org/notes/ltn007.html)
- [HTMLTitleElement.webidl](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/webidl/HTMLTitleElement.webidl)
- [SVGTitleElement.webidl](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/webidl/SVGTitleElement.webidl)
- [SVGScriptElement.webidl](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/webidl/SVGScriptElement.webidl)
- [HTMLScriptElement.webidl](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/webidl/HTMLScriptElement.webidl)
- [The names of functions in ES6](http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html)
- [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification - 19.2.4.2 Function Instances: name | ECMA-262 6th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-name)