# Can anyone explain namespace in javascript with an example?

Tags: javascript

I am bit confused with namespaces of function in javascript. Can I have function with same names?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/ has some good examples on this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no official concept of a namespace in Javascript like there is in C++. However, you can wrap functions in Javascript objects to emulate namespaces. For example, if you wanted to write a function in a "namespace" called `MyNamespace`, you might do the following:

```
var MyNamespace = {};

MyNamespace.myFunction = function(arg1, arg2) {
    // do things here
};

MyNamespace.myOtherFunction = function() {
    // do other things here
};
```

Then, to call those functions, you would write `MyNamespace.myFunction(somearg, someotherarg);` and `MyNamespace.myOtherFunction();`.

I should also mention that there are many different ways to do namespacing and class-like things in Javascript. My method is just one of those many.

For more discussion, you might also want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021/is-there-a-concise-way-to-do-namespacing-in-javascript) question.

Comment: A capital first letter usually implies that it's a constructor. It might be better to use `myNamespace` instead.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of personal coding style, really. I always use first letters for class names and constructors. In this case, `MyNamespace` is acting as a class.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no JavaScript implementations support namespaces, if you're referring to ECMAScript 6/JavaScript 2 namespaces.

If you're referring to how namespacing is done today, it's just the use of one object and putting every method you want to define onto it.

```
var myNamespace = {};
myNamespace.foo = function () { /*...*/ };
myNamespace.bar = function () { /*...*/ };
```