# Does javascript autobox?

Tags: javascript

While working on another problem, I created this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tr2by/

```
function foo() {
    // console.log(_.isBoolean(this));
    console.log(this === true);
}

foo.call(true); // object:[object Boolean]
foo.apply(true); // object:[object Boolean]
```

Is this an example of auto-boxing?

Going from a value type to a reference type.

Here is a [wikipedia def.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Autoboxing)

Comment: Boxing in Javascript is very different from other languages.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that particular behavior "auto-boxing", because the value `true` is (almost certainly) passed as the boolean primitive itself. The conversion to an object (probably) is done explicitly by the implementation of `.call()` and `.apply()`.

Comment: ... but see [this section of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) concerning the semantics of a "Reference".  I think that's more like what I'd call "auto-boxing", had I the need to call it anything.

Comment: Actually the answer that Mr. Kling posted would make my guess wrong; it seems that the coercion to Object type happens differently.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First of all I assume you are talking about automatic conversion of primitive values to objects. This happens in two cases in JavaScript:

1. When you pass a primitive value as the `this` value to `.call` or `.apply` (not in strict mode though).
2. When you are trying to access a "property" of a primitive value, e.g. `"foo bar".split()`.

In the first case the conversion is permanent, i.e. `this` will indeed reference an object, in the second the conversion only takes place internally for the duration of the evaluation

If you are not interested in the details of the conversion, you can ignore the rest of the answer.

---

**1. Primitive value as `this`**

When a function is exectued and its `this` value is not an object, it is converted to one, at least in non-strict mode. This is described in [§10.4.3 Entering Function Code *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3) in the ECMAScript 5.1 documentation:

> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for function code contained in function object `F`, a caller provided `thisArg`, and a caller provided `argumentsList`:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the `ThisBinding` to `thisArg`.
> 2. Else if `thisArg` is `null` or `undefined`, set the `ThisBinding` to the global object.
> 3. Else if `Type(thisArg)` is not `Object`, set the `ThisBinding` to `ToObject(thisArg`).
>      [...]

As you can see in step three the value is converted to an object by calling [`ToObject` *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9).

**2. Property access**

Something similar happens when you are trying to access properties ([§11.2.1 Property Accessors *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1)). The quoted part here explains how the expression `foo[bar]` is evaluated, i.e. how property access with the bracket notation is evaluated. The part we are interested in applies to dot notation as well.

> The production `MemberExpression : MemberExpression [ Expression ]` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `baseReference` be the result of evaluating `MemberExpression`.
> 2. Let `baseValue` be `GetValue(baseReference)`.
>      [...]
>
> 8. Return a value of type `Reference` whose `base` value is `baseValue` and whose referenced name is `propertyNameString`, and whose `strict` mode flag is `strict`.

The important step is the last one: No matter to what `MemberExpression` evaluates, it is  converted to a value of type [`Reference` *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7). This is a datatype only used in the specification and contains additional information about how the actual value should be retrieved from the reference (not to be confused with object references in actual JavaScript code!).

To get the "real" value/result from such a reference, the internal function [`GetValue(V)` (§8.7.1) *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) is called (just like in step 2 in the above algorithm), where it says:

> The following `[[Get]]` internal method is used by `GetValue` when `V` is a property reference with a primitive base value. It is called using `base` as its `this` value and with property `P` as its argument. The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let `O` be `ToObject(base)`.
>      [...]

**Example:**

Assume we have the expression

```
var foo = "BAR".toLowerCase();
```

This is an assignment expression which is evaluated as follows:

> The production `AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `LeftHandSideExpression`.
> 2. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `AssignmentExpression`.
> 3. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
>      [...]

Step 1: The left hand side is evaluated, which is the identifier `foo`. How exactly identifiers are resolved is not important for this.
Step 2: The right hand side is evaluated, i.e. `"BAR".toLowerCase()`. The **internal** result of that evaluation will be a reference value, similar to:

```
REFERENCE = {
    base: "BAR",
    propertyNameString: "toLowerCase",
    strict: false
}
```

and stored in `rref`.

Step 3: `GetValue(rref)` is called. The `base` of the reference is the value `"BAR"`. Since this is a primitive value, `ToObject` will be called to convert it to a *temporary* `String` object. Furthermore, the reference is actually a *property access*, so `GetValue` will eventually call the method `toLowerCase` on the `String` object and return the method's result.

Comment: Do you know what happens in strict mode then? I guess I could test it myself, but...

Comment: ... and I guess that in strict mode, that step 2 is different, leaving `this` set to `undefined`, right?

Comment: @Ian In strict mode, we finish setting `this` at step 1. The `this` is the actual primitive value.

Comment: - where is `ThisBinding` and `thisArg` defined ... does this even cover the auto-boxing

Comment: @Pointy: It's an `if ... else` statement (hard to see, I know). Step 2 is not executed when the condition in step 1 is true.

Comment: @the_web_situation: `ThisBinding` is defined by the algorithm, `thisArg` is a value provided by the caller. I added the introductory sentence from the specification, but for a complete picture you might want to read it yourself.

Comment: @FelixKling Am I seriously that dumb? How did I miss that text? Haha sorry, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @the_web_situation: Added more information and an example regarding property access. If that's all too much information, I apologize, I just like to support my statements with solid facts :)

Comment: language specs, I wish they were picture books.

Comment: And IIUIC, this *temporary* `String` object is **immutable**.

Answer (score 6):

Javascript boxes the `this` argument provided to `call` and `apply` in non-strict mode. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Parameters):

> if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

Comment: @the_web_situation it depends on what you mean by "auto".

Comment: @the_web_situation I *suppose* you could say that -- it's a case of getting a boxed version of a primitive without writing code to perform the conversion explicitly. If you want to call that "autoboxing," go for it, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers provide detailed information about when autoboxing occurs, but here's a couple more things to remember:

- Autoboxing **does not** occur when using the `in` operator, which throws a `TypeError` if the value received is not an object. A simple solution is to manually box the object with `Object(value)`.
- Some form of autoboxing occurs when iterating using `for...of` or the spread syntax `[...value]` which allows strings to be iterated.

Comment: `for...of` and spread syntax both use the iteration protocol, which accesses the `Symbol.iterator` method on the iterable - a property access like on any other value.