# Why are JavaScript Primitive-Variables immutable and Object-Variables not?

Tags: javascript, oop

There is a way to add a member-function or member-property to Number, String, ect...-Variables with the help of the prototype-property:

```
 Number.prototype.member = function(){ console.log('number-member-function called'); };
```

or with help of the proto-property of the variables themselves:

```
 var num = 7;
 num.__proto__.member = function(){ console.log('number-member-function called'); };
```

Just like to any other kind of JavaScript-types.
But what is the difference of the implementation of Primtives and Objects in JavaScript so that the code below does not work for Numbers but for Objects?

```
 var num = 7;
 num.member = function(){ console.log('number-member-function called'); };
 num.member(); // TypeError: num.member is not a function

 var obj = {};
 obj.member = function(){ console.log('object-member-function called'); };
 obj.member(); // object-member-function called
```

Does anybody know approximatly how JavaScript Primitves and Objects are implemented under the hood? Because all JavaScript-implementations in all browsers must be done identically or almost for there is an error thrown with the Number-Function called member.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750880/javascript-how-does-new-work-internally some sort of useful info

Comment: As Giovanni said, primitive values are temporarily converted to objects. This is described in [section  8.7.2 in the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.2). `PutValue` is called when an [assignment](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1) takes place.

Comment: Related: [Does javascript autobox?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17216847/218196)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript)

Comment: The links above are very convincing too like the answer below but is anybody out there who knows how primitives and/or objects are implemented concretely in one browser for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the literal notation for the `boolean`, `string` and `number` types, the constructors (Boolean, String, Number) are not used.  The primitive types still behaves almost like they had been instantiated with the `new` operator, but are truly primitive types.

Only when you are trying to use them as objects or you are trying to use a property of a constructor, the JavaScript interpreter creates a wrapper object around them behind the scenes.
After this, the wrapper objects gets discarded and you are dealing again with the primitive type.
So:

```
var num = 7; //primitive

// You are trying to use num as an object: a wrapper object gets created and discarded just after the assignment
num.member = function(){ console.log('number-member-function called'); }; 

// This will throw an error, because here num is primitive again (member was defined on the discarded wrapper)
num.member();
```

More on this topic can be found on the book "JavaScript Enlightenment" by Cody Lindley, based on the ECMA-262, Edition 3 specification.

Comment: I would like to read more answers, too ;-) ! If you do not want to change the Number prototype, but still want to add a method to a number, the `new Number` can be used. Calling `Number(7)` returns the primitive 7 number, but calling `new Number(7)` returns a `Number` object that you can change and that works as you expect. `var x = new Number(2); x.alert = function(){ alert('hello'); }; x.alert()`

Comment: As I wrote ealier before I deleted it, your answer is very convincing, but please be not upset when I still want to wait for other answers too. :)

Comment: Hi @GiovanniFilardo, could you have a look at my question related with primitive immutability? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291111/how-to-understand-that-javascript-primitives-are-immutable, much appreciated!