# What is meant when we say that primitive values are immutable?

Tags: javascript, primitive

In [JavaScript Primitives](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp) it is written:

> Primitive values are immutable (they are hardcoded and therefore cannot be changed).

What does it mean?

Comment: The part about being hardcoded is pretty nonsensical, in typical W3S fashion.

Comment: What it basically means, is that you can change the value of a variable (`x = "a"`), but you can't change the value of a primitive value (`"a" = "b"` won't work)

Comment: Please do not refer to W3Schools for anything. They run a highly search-engine-optimized advertising business, not a web technologies documentation. Disregard their search hits, turn to the actual documentation instead.

Comment: @blex thanks for the answer. Obviously my question is not duplicate as it is no way related to said question. Please provide your comment as answer and remove the duplicate tag.

Comment: @Tomalak Please look at answer by blex and you will see how the question is not duplicate.

Comment: I agree that the mentioned question is not a duplicate of this one. Sorry, I don't have enough rights to remove the flag, and therefore I can't answer. However, I think people with more knowledge will be able to explain this better if your question gets re-opened.

Comment: Here's another duplicate. One among many. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115512/understanding-javascript-immutable-variable

Comment: And another one. You could have searched. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971503/why-are-javascript-primitive-variables-immutable-and-object-variables-not