# private prototype from within a class

Tags: javascript, prototype, private

Say I define a class `Template()` within which I need to extend `String` with some `prototype` to add functionalities to it:

```
function Template() {
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replace) {
        return this.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1"), 'g'), replace);
    }

    this.test = function (){
        return "hello".replaceAll("h", "y");
    }
}
```

Now if I declare a `new Template()`, the `String.prototype` is public:

```
var myTemplate = new Template();
console.log(myTemplate.test()); // outputs "yello", this is desired
console.log("hello".replaceAll("h", "y")); // outputs "yello", this should not work
```

Whereas what I would want is for `String` to go unchanged outside of the `Template()` class while still being extended from within.

How do you declare a private prototype from within a class in javascript?

Comment: You don't. The prototype of a type is global (or, at least as global as the type itself).

Comment: there is no such thing as "private" in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *general*, you do the opposite; you create a new function, whose prototype is the "class" you want to extend, then you add the new methods to that function;

```
function MyString() {

}

MyString.prototype = new String();
MyString.prototype.replaceAll = function (find, replace) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1"), 'g'), replace);
};
```

... you can create `MyString` in whatever scope, so that it is as private or public as you want. Then, inside your scope you create instances of `MyString` rather than `String`. This gives you the extra ("private") prototypes you want.

**However**, string is a primitive, and primitives don't work like normal objects; specifically, [they are autoboxed/ upcast to objects when you call methods on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216847/does-javascript-autobox). This will mean the above is not usable in your situation; as `"abc".replaceAll()` will always autobox to a `String`, not `MyString`; and you can't tell JavaScript to do otherwise.

***Instead***, what you *should* be doing (since you shouldn't modify what you don't own anyway), is creating a helper function which you pass the string into to do your dirty work;

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1"), 'g'), replace);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible due to `String` is a global object. It doesn't matter where you change it or its prototype, it will be affected everywhere.

In your case you should declare a helper function within your class.

```
function Template() {

    function stringReplaceAll(str, search, replace) {}

}
```

This one will only be available in your class.