# alert( 20e-1['toString'](2) ); javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know what will alert this javascript expression

```
alert( 20e-1['toString'](2) );
```

and I need detailed explanations about the answer.

Thank You for detailed answer!

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: try here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: 20e-1 = 2 (mathematical operation). It is of a type "number" which is also an Object in javascript. Thus, we can write 2.someMethod(); Here, you call the toString() method, with brackets notation (and not dot notation) : 20e-1['toString'], which returns a litteral expression. Finally, you call the method with parenthesis, and add a parameter 2 to the method, which is the basis of the result, here a binary result. So... We have a 2 converted into a binary number => 10 which is expressed as a string '10'.

Answer (score 7):

The result will be `10`.

Let's dissect the expression `20e-1['toString'](2)`:

- `20e-1` is a floating point number specified in scientific notation, which is a shorthand for `20 * 10^-1 ( = 20 * 0.1 = 2)`.
- `toString` is a property of a primitive value, the floating point number `2`. `toString` is a function that converts the number to its string representation. The syntax *suggests* that the primitive value is promoted into a `Number` object whose property `toString` is then referenced ( the reality is more complex,and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217024) will explain it in much better informed way than I could repeat).
- `(2)` is the list of actual parameters to the method `toString`. The single parameter specifies a conversion of the number to the string representation in base 2. `2` in base 2 representtaion happens to be `10` which explains the output.