# What's the meaning of the phrase: String 'wraps around' a string primitive value

Tags: javascript

On this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript) it says:

> Except for null and undefined, all primitive values have object
> equivalents that wrap around the primitive values:

I am aware of `String`, `Number` etc. and what they can do (i.e. when used as a function they can convert their arguments into a data-type) but what does it mean to say that they are 'wrap around primitive values'?

Comment: "wrap around" and "wrapper" are common terms for objects like that. It's not specific to JavaScript.

Comment: Search for autoboxing

Comment: @Pointy So another word for the concept of 'boxing' as mentioned in the answer here?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106836/how-does-javascript-temporarily-treat-string-primitives-as-instances-of-string-c/63107092?noredirect=1#comment111594212_63107092)

Comment: Yes, it's the same concept as "boxing".

Answer (score -1):

The statement made on this website reflects the idea that all of the primitive data types (string, booleans etc...) have a general word that represents the. For the string datatype, it is String. For the boolean datatype, it is Boolean. Most of the time, the wrap-around primitive values are just the capitalization of the datatypes.

Comment: I think the question is about the terminology