# Does autoboxing only happen when the . operator is used in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When you use the `.` operator on a variable that is a primitive data type, the variable will be autoboxed, for example:

```
var str = "Hello World";  // str is of type string

console.log(str.length);  // a temporary object of type String will be created
```

But does autoboxing only happen when the `.` operator is used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does javascript autobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216847/does-javascript-autobox)

Comment: have a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Answer (score 0):

No, it's used whenever you access a property on a primitive, which has a corresponding constructor.

E.g.

```
'abc'[2] // this will access 'c'
```

As you can see, no '.' accesor was used.