# How does instanceof operator actually work in JS?

Tags: javascript

I've searched the site for this question and got the following answer:

```js
function instance_of(V, F) {
  var O = F.prototype;
  V = V.__proto__;
  while (true) {
    if (V === null)
      return false;
    if (O === V)
      return true;
    V = V.__proto__;
  }
}
```

It's from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220317/12974414.

But I tested the following code, found something weird:

```js
console.log( (10).__proto__ === Number.prototype ) // true
console.log( instance_of(10, Number ) )            // true
console.log( 10 instanceof Number )                // false

function instance_of(V, F) {
  var O = F.prototype;
  V = V.__proto__;
  while (true) {
    if (V === null)
      return false;
    if (O === V)
      return true;
    V = V.__proto__;
  }
}
```

How to explain this and how does instanceof operator actually work in JS ?

Comment: [Here's the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-instanceofoperator)

Comment: Also may be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript

Comment: The function is correct when used *with objects*. It aims to clarify the behaviour in those cases, not add in excessive logic for handling primitives which would detract from the explanation.

Comment: `instanceof` works for objects, not for primitive values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has a feature called autoboxing which [converts primitives to Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217024/19068) when you try to access properties on them.

`instanceof` doesn't autobox and a primitive number is not an instance of the Number class.

You can see, [in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-ordinaryhasinstance):

> 3. If Type(O) is not Object, return false.